# Is there a way to get a specific string out of a route in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

Say I have a route that is http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Is there a way I can read through that link and check the see if the word "ask" is there?

So,

```
If(link.contains["ask"]) {
     containsAsk = true;
}
```

To be clear, I am trying to pull the link from the browser, and do not have it defined within my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: I want to get the link from the browser, not a string I've defined in the code

Comment: you could querie the router to get the current route which will return a string, then check it for a sub string.

Comment: Ok - what have you already tried? What version of angular are you using? Please add some more information to your question to help get a good answer

Comment: Could you specify what angular is this question related to? angular2/4 or angularjs? to apply the correct tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In angular2/4 you could inject into a component an instance of `ActivatedRoute`, transform it to string with `toString()` and check the value of it. For example

```
@Component()
export class TestComponent{
   constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute){
     let link = _route.toString();
     console.log(link.contains('ask'));
   }
}
```

Note that this method will return a string with the form `Route(url:'${url}', path:'${matched}')`

If you want to traverse the singular elements that compose that link, you can navigate up to the root using the parent attribute of the instance.

More info in  [the following link](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#toString)

Another option would be to directly inject the Router into the component, what will directly allow you to get the current url:

```
@Component()
    export class TestComponent{
       constructor(private _router: Router){
         let link = _router.url();
         console.log(link.contains('ask'));
       }
    }
```